# Can C# style interfaces be used in Fortran, or any other ideas for common Fortran libraries?

Tags: c#, interface, fortran

I am looking for some advice about how to structure some FORTRAN libraries.  I have a variety of programs that have similar, but different data structures and wish to use these structures in common libraries to avoid duplication of code.

Options:

1. Force the data structures to be the same by forcing a common definition that includes all fields needed by any application.   Feels like a bad decision since the usage of the data structures varies greatly program to program.
2. use inheritance and have a common ancestor for each type defined to have only the fields needed by the common libraries.  Not bad, but forces common single inheritance tree.
3. Use interfaces in the C# sense, where an established group of related fields are guaranteed but no ancestry is required.  Sounds nice, but not sure if possible in FORTRAN.
4. Find a magic converter program that will convert FORTRAN into C#.  My testing in the past found that this "might" be possible, but the generated code would be mangled and painful to maintain.
5. Manual conversion to another language.  This is seductive, but the code base is so large that it will take years to migrate manually.
6. Something else.

Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: At the very least, you need to specify which version of Fortran you are using.

Comment: I don't think he has to. There only one valid ISO Fortran standard valid at the time, The present one informally known as Fortran 2008.

Comment: For #4 I suggest looking under a toadstool.  I'd like to be told I'm wrong and that there is a production-ready, weapons-grade Fortran-to-C# translator available, but I bet I won't be.

Comment: I am using Intel Visual Fortran XE which implements almost all of the Fortran 2003 standard and much of the Fortran 2008 standard.

Answer (score 1):

If common inheritance from an abstract type (your #2) is not desirable, then the typical approach to this is to write your types such that they have the necessary consistency of interface, then put the common code in a separate file that is brought in using INCLUDE files.  Type parameterization can be achieved using things like USE renaming and implicit typing.

This is an approximation to your #3.

"Use renaming" refers to the ability to rename an entity in a USE statement to be different from the name of the entity in the module being USE'd.  This allows you to do ...

```
USE some_module, ONLY: name_wanted_by_included_source => original_name
INCLUDE 'some_source'
```

and then the included source works with `name_wanted_by_included_source`, regardless of whatever the entity name is in your original code.

Implicit typing can be used to do something similar, with the usual downside associated with implicit typing:

```
IMPLICIT TYPE(my_type_name)(Q)
INCLUDE 'some_other_source'
```

Any entities in some_other_source that start with the letter Q (and not declared otherwise) will be of type `my_type_name`.

Some use tools external to Fortran, such as the C preprocessor or PyF95++, to do similar templating of code.

Comment: Thanks @IanH.  Although you do not directly say it, your approach suggests that the 2008 FORTRAN standard does not have the ability to do inheritance directly, but I can do a slight of hand that will get me closer.  Is this correct?  

I am having trouble finding documentation on "USE renaming" and "implicit typing" any links you can suggest?  I would like to review your proposal, but I am thinking option #2 is my best bet.

Comment: Inheritance is certainly supported "directly" - hence your #2 is an option.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry I meant interfaces.  Are interfaces supported in the Java/C# sense in Fortran 2008?

Comment: No. The only in-language support is via inheritance from an abstract type.